# Codeception uncheckOption() does not work

Tags: php, phalcon, codeception

I'm writing an acceptance test for a form. The test checks a checkbox, tests if the checkbox is checked and than unchecks it.

So I have the following snippet in my view:

```
 <form>
    <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="agree"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree">Agree to the conditions!
    </div>
</form>
```

and in my acceptance test I do:

```
/* works */
$I->seeElement('#agree');
$I->dontSeeCheckboxIsChecked('#agree');
$I->checkOption('#agree');
$I->seeCheckboxIsChecked('#agree');
/* This does not work?*/
$I->uncheckOption('#agree');
$I->cantSeeCheckboxIsChecked('#agree');
```

I'm using the `PhpBrowser` driver as I could not get the `WebDriver` driver to work behind the corporate firewall.

While `seeElement` and `seeCheckboxIsChecked` confirm that the checkbox exists and is checked, the following `uncheckOption` does not succeed.

Output from test is:

```
2) Failed to check checkbox in WelcomeCept (tests\functional\\WelcomeCept.php)

 Step  I can dont see checkbox is checked "#agree"
 Fail  Failed asserting that 1 matches expected 0.

Scenario Steps:

     11. $I->canDontSeeCheckboxIsChecked("#agree") at tests\functional\WelcomeCept.php:18
     10. $I->uncheckOption("#agree") at tests\functional\WelcomeCept.php:17
     9. $I->seeCheckboxIsChecked("#agree") at tests\functional\WelcomeCept.php:15
     8. $I->checkOption("#agree") at tests\functional\WelcomeCept.php:14
     7. $I->dontSeeCheckboxIsChecked("#agree") at tests\functional\WelcomeCept.php:13
     6. $I->seeElement("#agree") at tests\functional\WelcomeCept.php:12
```

FYI I'm using the Phalcon framework and its Volt templating engine and the page behaves correctly in the browser.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uncheckOptions works, the problem is that CheckboxIsChecked assertions check the source of the page and not the form values set by the test.

https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2355#issuecomment-139166355

> The $I->dontSeeCheckboxIsChecked() method runs an Xpath query against
>   the generated HTML and looks for a checked attribute on the input
>   element you specify.

Comment: Thanks. I finally got the Webdriver module working (had to unset proxy environment variables) and now this kind of test is possible.